# How can I use _RANDOM_SEED in colab?

Tags: python, random-seed

I was trying to use _RANDOM_SEED from python_utils module but I had this error

AttributeError: module 'python_utils' has no attribute '_RANDOM_SEED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't `import random`.

you can use `random`

```
import random
random.seed(365)
```

You can use `numpy`.

```
import numpy as np; 
np.random.seed(365)
```

Comment: thanks dear,but I wanna use utils module..
Also I have met another issue when I use any attribute from utils I get the same AtrributeError

Comment: @MajdAlhafi did you install python_utils. try this : `pip install python_utils`

Comment: @MajdAlhafi python_utils don't have _RANDOM_SEED read this link, function that this library have you can see : https://python-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html